# Splitting string with regexp in Perl when delimeter appears in the beginning of the string

Tags: regex, string, perl, split, delimiter

I want to split a string using **regular expressions** but I have run into some problem. I have this string:

```
$text=" one two three";
```

Then I try to split it into alphabetic words:

```
#@words=split(" ", $text);          #1 this works

@words=split("[^a-zA-Z]", $text);   #2 this doesn't work

for $word (@words){
    printf "word: |$word|\n";
}
```

So the commented method(*1*) works fine. As expected I get printed:

```
word: |one|
word: |two|
word: |three|
```

However with the second method(*2*) I get this:

```
word: ||
word: |one|
word: |two|
word: |three|
```

So although logically the second method should be equivalent to the first one, in practice it doesn't behave the same way. Why is that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a special case in Perl's `split()` function.

As stated in [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> `split(/PATTERN/, expr, [limit])`
>
> If PATTERN is omitted, [it] splits on whitespace (after skipping any 
>   leading whitespace).
>
> Empty leading fields are produced when there are positive-width
>   matches at the beginning of the string; [...]
>
> As a special case, specifying a PATTERN of space (`' '`) will split on
>   white space just as split with no arguments does. Thus, `split(' ')` can
>   be used to emulate awk's default behavior, whereas `split(/ /)` will
>   give you as many initial null fields (empty string) as there are
>   leading spaces.

Comment: Thanks. In the end I just solved it by checking the length of the `$word`